# What drinks are SURELY known to affect and/or differ Franky's behaviour?

Tags: one-piece

It is known that Franky is powered by cola in his stomach fridge, so if other liquids are used, his behaviour goes through drastic changes.

So far, I'm aware of two cases in Enies Lobby and one in the Future Kingdom, right before the Impel Down events.

Is someone able to provide a complete list?

Comment: Could you include the drinks that were used in the cases you cited? And also either an episode or a chapter course for these instances?

Comment: @Cyberson vegetable juice at Enies Lobby and green tea at the Future Kingdom,can't recall episode number though,

Comment: You might want to add that into your question body, and look up those episodes because that will help people to be able to find the answer easier.

Comment: @Cyberson the cases when these happened are really obvious and noticeble, maybe even borderline memorial. I doubt it's necessary to explain further

Comment: I've read the entirety of One Piece, and I remember that the events do happen, just not a when. Knowing this, it would probably benefit people trying to help you if you included episodes.

Comment: There are many in Enies Lobby, remember when chopper gave Franky different type of juices from the refrigerator? One of the CP9 is inside that ref. when chopper is doing it. >_<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though Cola is the known drink used to power franky himself and his body it is shown that other drinks can also affect his personality. Used as a trope by Chopper in Enies Lobby, it was used as a plot point in his stay in the Future(?) Kingdom where he becomes gentleman like when tea is used. And reverts when it fizzes.

From the wiki

> It was shown during Franky's fight with Fukuro that depending on what kind of drink Franky has, it can change his hair style and attitude when Chopper accidentally hands him **vegetable juice and tea**. It also shows that Franky's strength is many times greater when he has more bottles of cola in his stomach fridge, and he needs it as a fuel for certain attacks. His hair acts as a kind of meter to the amount of cola in his stomach, being tall if he is full and sagging if empty. Franky's stomach compartment can hold up to three bottles, or six liters, of cola.

So Canonically only three drinks are known through which Franky's personality alters viz. Vegetable Juice and two kinds of tea.

http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Franky/Abilities_and_Powers